# Jenkins GitHub Organization pipeline 'checkout scm' fails on agent (slave/node)

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

On Linux, I am setting up a GitHub Organization folder to build pull requests.  Upon seeing a pull reqeust, the Master does a clone of the remote remote repository, starts executing the Jenkinsfile.   This clone is successful

The Jenkinfile is then executed and the first step is 'checkout scm'. Which fails miserably.

I have tried both SSH and HTTPS, and both fail in the agent the same way, albiet, with HTTPS, it uses GIT_ASKPASS instead of GIT_SSH.

I attempted to print the contents of env.GIT_SSH, and the result is null.

I am able to fetch from the respostory manually on the agent, using the same credentials, and it works ok, so it don't seem to be a keys issue.

Is it correct that GIT_SSH should be NULL?   Is there a way to unset GIT_SSH, and just use the credentials that are on the agent (which work).??

```
22:12:57 Cloning the remote Git repository
22:12:57 Cloning repository git@github.com:BC/zA.git
22:12:57  > git init /var/jenkins/workspace/tion_zA_PR-265-head-4KZDN3K54TSHW2MGKTNQGMP4QCTNKXIO4X54MUP32ONUC7LFQ3UQ # timeout=10
22:12:58 Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:BC/zA.git
22:12:58  > git --version # timeout=10
22:12:58 using GIT_SSH to set credentials Github Jenkins Master
22:12:58 ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
22:12:58 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to setup credentials
22:12:58    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1515)
22:12:58    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
22:12:58    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
22:12:58    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:512)
22:12:58    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
22:12:58    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
22:12:58    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
22:12:58    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
```